# Entity Framework remove self from database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am relatively new to Entity Framework, but so far I found questions to all my answers on Stackoverflow, except for what I will explain below.

Let's say I have a class `Person` generated by Entity Framework which looks like this:

```
public partial class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now I would like to remove a person by using the following bit of code:

```
using(databaseEntities db = new databaseEntities())
{
    Person person = db.Person.First(p => p.Id = 1);
    person.Remove();
}
```

Therefore I created a partial class with a remove method in it.

```
public partial class Person
{
    public void Remove()
    {
        using(databaseEntities db = new databaseEntities())
        {
            Person person = db.Person.First(p => p.Id == this.Id);
            db.Person.Remove(person);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

However, now I am removing the person from the database, but it is being removed in a different context.

How would I have to rewrite the `Person.Remove()` method, so that it would remove itself from the same `databaseContext`?

Comment: You should not create this `Remove()` method in your `Persion` class. This breaks your data model. A `Person` is not a container, but an entity. So you should remove the object directly from the `DbContext`.

Comment: In most designs, the entities themlelves do not interact with the data source.  The most popular design is using a _repository_ to handle CRUD operations rather then having entity methods.

Comment: To materialize both of our comments, `person.Remove();` should be `db.Person.Remove(person); db.SaveChanges();`

Comment: Okay thanks all! My reasoning was to put it in the partial class, because I wanted to group all methods together, which were related to a person.

Comment: The common way to do that organization is to create a `PersonRepository` class that provides all the methods for the DB context related to Person entities

Comment: Thank you for providing the `Repository` keyword. Now I know what to look for :) Also, now I know how much I need to rewrite haha